# Initialize variable and change it later in if condition

Tags: java, variables, initialization

I'm trying to get let1 initialized while still having it be manipulated by the if condition I set up for av1.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class School {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner get=new Scanner(System.in);

        //Variables
        String Stud1, Stud2, Stud3, Stud4;
        int num1S1, num2S1, num3S1, num4S1;
        int num1S2, num2S2, num3S2, num4S2;
        int num1S3, num2S3, num3S3, num4S3;
        int num1S4, num2S4, num3S4, num4S4;
        double av1, av2, av3, av4;
        char let1,let2,let3,let4;

        //Input Student One
        System.out.println("Please enter name of first student:");
        Stud1=get.next();
        System.out.print("Integer grades from 1st to fourth grade:\n");
        num1S1=get.nextInt();
        num2S1=get.nextInt();
        num3S1=get.nextInt();
        num4S1=get.nextInt();

        //Computing Average
        av1= (num1S1+num2S1+num3S1+num4S1)/4.0;
        av2= (num1S2+num2S2+num3S2+num4S2)/4.0;
        av3= (num1S3+num2S3+num3S3+num4S3)/4.0;
        av4= (num1S4+num2S4+num3S4+num4S4)/4.0;

        //If Statements for letter grade
        if(av1<=50)
            let1='F';
        if(av1>=60 && av1<=69)
            let1='D';
        if(av1>=70 && av1<=79)
            let1='C';
        if(av1>=80 && av1<=89)
            let1='B';
        if(av1>=90)
            let1='A';
        //Output

        System.out.printf("Studnet Name Grades Average Letter Grade\n");
        System.out.printf("%s %1d %1d %1d %1d %1.2f %c \n",Stud1,num1S1,num2S1,num3S1,num4S1,av1,let1); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could initialise `let1` to some arbitrary value when you declare it.

```
char let1 = ' ',let2,let3,let4;
```

Or you could change your if-structure to an if-else structure. That structure would probably make more sense if the cases were mutually exclusive which they probably are in this scenario. Also if you assign a value to `let1` in the `else` statement your compiler should stop complaining about uninitialized values.

Example:

```
if(av1<=50)
    let1='F';
else if(av1>=60 && av1<=69)
    let1='D';
/* Your other statements here */
else 
    let1 = 'A';
```

You might want to check your conditions as well. Your code currently doesn't deal with the case where the average grade is between 51 and 59.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below the declaration statement of let1

```
let1 = ' ';
```

Comment: The reason why it show the declaration error is because the let1 variable gets value only when inside if loop. In case the if loop is not executed the let1 will not be initialized. It is better to provide a default value like empty character space before you start using the variable in a loop.